# How to override bootstrap.properties OR how to ignore cloud config for local environment in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-parameter-store

I have an application [Spring boot app] which runs in local, dev env. I have used AWS parameter store configuration in `bootstrap.properties` file as below :

```
aws.paramstore.enabled = true
aws.paramstore.prefix = /abc
aws.paramstore.name = xyz/jkl/wer
```

These are my dependencies in `pom.xml` file :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.263</version>
    </dependency>
```

The app is running fine with the above configurations. However every time when I need to run my app in local, I need to comment out the above dependencies otherwise it throws error because these jars are in classpath and they complain about few connection not found etc.

I am trying to figure out some possibilities where I don't have to make any changes in the pom.xml for running the app with local-properties.

I tried to set the below property to false in bootstrap and enabled it in `application-dev.properties` file, however the app is not picking up the bootstrap configs in dev.

```
#false in bootstrap, enabled in application-dev.properties
aws.paramstore.enabled = false
```

Can you help me out to resolve this issue. I do not wish to comment out the dependencies in pom every time I run my app in local. What trick can I use here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way to do that in eclipse :

[image: Eclipse-Run-Configurations]

However the main question remains valid though, how can we override bootstrap properties in our application environment wise.